# Linksys WRT54GS V6 Router Blinking Power Light

Tags: wireless-router

I have a Linksys WRT54GS V6 Router in my possession got it at my local goodwill for 5$. Upon start up the Power LED starts flashing like crazy and at the same time the Ethernet ports all light up once then turn off (DMZ and WLAN never turn on). I can ping the router only by setting a static IP on my Pc. I can also successfully push a file (official Linksys OS and DD-wrt) into it via TFTP but this currently does nothing (no 192.1681.1 Access).

Any ideas as to what may be wrong? I think its pretty obvious that it's bricked but.. 
I keep hearing a whole lot of "if it pings it's fixable" on the internet.

Comment: Did you do a hard reset of the router?, usually this flashing means it is toast, not much you can do but donate it to Goodwill.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like someone tried pushing a custom firmware onto it and bricked it in the process, gave up, and gave it to Goodwill. You make want to consult [This Documentation](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Version_5_And_6_Router_Information) to see if it is recoverable by returning it to its factory settings.

Since you are able to ping it and get an IP via static configuration, it sounds like the firmware usually means it's made it past the bootloader and the NVRAM is either missing the OS or it is one that is incompatible with the device. Depending on how bad of shape it is in, you may end up having to take it apart and solder in a serial port to it.

Good luck!